# Intersection from different keys inside Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, intersection

I am trying to find not only the intersection, but the differences between two sets with ID's inside my dict. 
The structure of my dict is:

```
dict_all[key] = {"id_yes" : None, "id_no" : None ,"ZUW_yes": set(), "ZUW_no": set(), "missing_ZUW_yes" : set(), "missing_ZUW_no" : set()}
```

The dict is getting filled before, except

```
"missing_ZUW_yes" : set(), "missing_ZUW_no" : set()
```

these two are supposed to take the missing id's from comparing `"ZUW_yes": set(), "ZUW_no": set()`.
That means missing_ZUW_yes has to contain the object which are in `ZUW_no` but not in `ZUW_yes`.

I tried to build the intersection by doing this:

```
def intersection(dict_all):
overlap = [k for k in dict_all[key]["ZUW_yes"] if in dict_all[key]["ZUW_no"]]
```

In the following I wanted to compare the single yes and no sets with the intersection to find the differennces and fill in the missing dict entries.

I did this before with some for loops but it took far too long, because the data inside the dict is quite huge..

Comment: Have you thought of the built-in [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) method for sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your sets are *sets* you can just use the proper set operations they provide: `ZUW_no - ZUW_yes` will give you everything that's in `ZUW_no` but not in `ZUW_yes`.

If you prefer a more literate version, `-` is an alias for `set_a.difference(b)`. Note that the method form can also take multiple parameters so `a - b - c - d` (aka `a - (b | c | d)`) can also be written `a.difference(b, c, d)`.

`set` has [a number of very useful set-operations provided out of the box](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) you probably want to take a look at, most of them are pretty clear (in my opinion the only somewhat ambiguous one is `symmetric_difference` as it computes `(a-b) | (b-a)` aka `(a|b) - (a&b)`, while its naming could *also* have it be a shorthand for `a-b, b-a`)